# how to find distance/length/size of an object using bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, triangulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Measure distance and height of an object using Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932920/how-to-measure-distance-and-height-of-an-object-using-android)

how to detect an object and calculate distance of an object using radio waves of bluetooth device using android please give me some idea .without using sensor devices to detect or to calculate distance of an object using only bluetooth device ....

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth API doesnt return Latitude,Longitude or Altitude co-ordinates, and without such the information, you can not get your requirements to be fulfill. The only way you can assume is if the device is not discovered you may assume that device is out of bluetooth's normal range 10 meters. No other information you can fetch it.

But yes, if your device is such that smart bluetooth device, which sents its own information like you asked, then you may surely fetch it.

Comment: hello ..suppose with the help of gps if we obtain latittude r longitude how to calculate distance of an object ? is it possible to identify an object using bluetooth ? as we do using camera .

Comment: whats your actual requirement ? i am not getting you.